# cant display table anymore (phpmyadmin)

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I did some SQL queries through the `phpMyAdmin` interface (only select). All the sudden I can't display one of the tables anymore.

Neither through the "browse" tab nor through an SQL command using the * operator.

Both methods: 
Clicking the "browse" tab or executing

```
SELECT * FROM `rosters` WHERE 1
```

return the following error

```
 #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1
```

If I return specific fields like

```
SELECT `id`, `league_id`, `player_id`, `fflteam_id`, `season`, `active`, `contract`, `pick_id`, `created`, `modified` FROM `rosters` WHERE 1
```

which are all fields the table contains, the table is displayed.

Even stranger is that other users don't have that problem.

Comment: Try taking out the `WHERE 1` and see what happens.

Comment: Can you show the query you have the problem?

Comment: On second thought thank you Mike.  The error is referring to SQL syntax that is not in the query you posted.  Are you sure there is not another query Cheetah?

Comment: that is the query i have the problem with. thats the strange thing. only thing i know is that phpmyadmin paginates the results and usually displays only 30 results per page. in fact phpmyadmin usually adds 'limit 0,30' to every query i write into the query box

Comment: @steinmas same result if i delete WHERE 1

Comment: Try clicking the Repair Table link from the Operations tab for that table. What happens if you try the SELECT *... statement from the command-line client?

Comment: possible duplicate of [phpmyadmin cannot open table's browse view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24190683/phpmyadmin-cannot-open-tables-browse-view)