# phpmyadmin cannot open table's browse view

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I had a table open in phpmyadmin using the browse view, and entered an incorrect query. Unfortunately, I restarted my browser before correcting the view, and I cannot open browse view to correct the error. Every time I open the table, I get the following popup:

`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DEC,x ASC,z ASC LIMIT 0,30' at line 1`

Closing this popup by clicking it leaves me on the page I was already on instead of allowing me to correct the error. Please note that I have checked that the table is ok, and that I can open the table in other views and from other programs, meaning this error is an inconvenience, but will not stop me from working all together. Furthermore, no other tables are affected.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I figured it out. Click the icon to the left of the table to open the list of columns, select all columns, and click "Browse" next to the text "with selected". Then, click the edit button in the sql code at the top of the page, and paste:

`SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME
 ORDER BY COLUMN_NAME DESC`

This will make the default browse view for that table sort the table by COLUMN_NAME in descending order, overwriting the corrupt default sort. I'm leaving this up because I spent at least an hour searching google and the documentation for a solution with no luck whatsoever.

Comment: This should be documented somewhere in the phpMyAdmin docs. (maybe it is but I've never been able to find it). If the phpMyAdmin "configuration storage tables" tables exist for your database you may be able to find the default query for the "Browse" view in them and fix it there. Unfortunately if those tables don't exist phpMyAdmin still manages to cache (modifiable) default queries in an unknown location. This answer allows the those queries to be overwritten for the table "Browse" views. Pure gold.

Comment: I have no idea how you figured this out, thanks a lot for sharing though!

Comment: I am lost.
I can click on table -> columns -> select all columns (check all) -> with selected BROWSE (as soon as I click on BROWSER) I am unable to do anything, as the page begins to load. There is no EDIT on top to change the code...HELP!

Comment: You also have to click on refresh button (right to the edit button) in the end.

Answer (score 1):

The last time you used the `Browse` tab of this table, you entered an SQL statement which contained

```
DEC,x ASC,z ASC LIMIT 0,30
```

While this contained faulty syntax - or syntax which went faulty when you changed something else in the database - it was still saved as your preference.

I'm not sure if this can be adjusted via the UI, but your MySQL admin can go to the `phpmyadmin` database and delete the faulty entry in the `pma__table_uiprefs` table.

Answer (score 0):

Megaton Solution: Open DevTools and clear all storage (Cookies, LocalStorage, IndexedDB)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem,
I clicked on 1 specific table in phpmyadmin and it would LOAD forevery, quit with ERROR PROCESSING after minutes (fastest solution was to restart apache2 to get access to phpmyadmin again).

It did not help to OPTIMIZE OR REPAIR the table.
I was not able to solve it by opening columns, select all and change the query.

My only solution was:
RENAME Table
COPY the table to xxx_save'
rename xxx_save to original

The copied table works fine.